# VB Excel ignore empty cells in range

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to tell a range to ignore any empty cells. For example I start my macro with,

```
Dim v, stMember
v = Sheets("Home").Range("B12:B14")
For Each stMember In v
```

As there is a value in `B12, B13 and B14` there shows no errors. But i would look to be able to expand the range to `B22` for example, however if there is nothing in a cell in the range i get error messages. Its from a user input so they will never enter more than 10 values, but could possibly enter less.

Below is the full code but its quite long so my apologies if not neccessary.

```
Sub createSummary()


Dim Val As String

Val = Sheets("Home").Range("B3").Value

If SheetExists(Val) Then

    MsgBox "Summary for " + Val + " already exists."

Else

Sheets.Add.Name = Val
Sheets(Val).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Dim v, stMember

v = Sheets("Home").Range("B12:B14")

For Each stMember In v

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(stMember)
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        ws.Activate
        If ws.Range("B" & i).Value = Val Then
            Range("B" & i).EntireRow.Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets(Val).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).Select
            ActiveCell.PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteValues
            Range("J" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = stMember

        End If
    Next i
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next stMember
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple [**IsEmpty()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227(v=office.15).aspx) should do;

```
if Not IsEmpty(stMember) then
    ' do something when not empty
...
```

Answer (score 1):

For testing if the sheet names exists you should go beyond testing for empty cells - for example sheet may not exist, the text in the cell may contain invalid characters etc.

A standard approach is to test whether a variable can be set - without an error - to that sheet name

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set ws1 = Sheets("sheetname from cell")
On Error GoTo 0

If Not ws1 Is Nothing Then
```

I have updated the code in full below to improve the speed

- `AutoFilter` much better than looping
- No need for `Activate`
- Turn `ScreenUpdating` off etc

**recut code**

```
Sub Recut()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim strSh As String

strSh = Sheets("Home").Range("B3").Value

On Error Resume Next
Set ws1 = Sheets(strSh)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not ws1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Summary for " + strSh + " already exists."
    Exit Sub
End If

Set ws1 = Sheets.Add
On Error Resume Next
ws1.Name = strSh
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox strSh & " is an invalid name"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set rng1 = Sheets("Home").Range("B12:B14")
For Each rng2 In rng1

On Error Resume Next
Set ws2 = Sheets(CStr(rng2.Value2))
On Error GoTo 0

If Not ws2 Is Nothing Then
    Set rng3 = ws2.Range(ws2.[b1], ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp))
    rng3.AutoFilter 1, strSh
    With rng3
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng4 = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rng4 Is Nothing Then
            rng4.EntireRow.Copy ws1.Cells(1 + lngCnt, 1)
            ws1.Cells(lngCnt + 1, "j").Resize(rng4.Cells.Count, 1) = rng2.Value
            lngCnt = lngCnt + rng4.Rows.Count
        End If
    End With
    ws2.AutoFilterMode = False
End If
Set ws2 = Nothing

Next

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```